# How do I read this line given to me by django debugger? (NoReverseMatch)

Tags: python, django, web

There are several posts on here already about NoReverseMatch, I've read the documentation and understand why I am receiving this error (what raised it) but I'm struggling to find out how to fix it.

I was originally going to post hoping someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong so I could fix it. I figured that wouldn't help me much so I instead was wondering if someone could tell me how to read this line:

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('', 2, 1)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects\\/categories\\/(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\,\\ (?P<category_id>[0-9]+)\\/(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)$']
```

Specifically:

```
['projects\\/categories\\/(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\,\\ (?P<category_id>[0-9]+)\\/(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)$']
```

Obviously, this is a common type of syntax used by Django (and I believe programming in general) so I'd rather be taught to understand this so I can then better debug these situations myself.

Thanks!

**Relevant Code**

index.html

```
{% block content %}
        <h1>Recent Projects</h1>
        {% for project in recent_projects %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'projects:detail' project.category.slug project.category.id project.id %}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'projects'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('categories/', views.categories, name='categories'),
    path('categories/<slug:slug>, <int:category_id>/', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
    path('categories/<slug:category_slug>, <int:category_id>/<int:project_id>', views.detail, name='detail')
]
```

The relevant view:

```
def detail(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    return render(request, 'projects/detail.html', {'project': project})
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about a "common syntax". That's a very specific message from Django's URL reverse matcher, and it's telling you that you're passing an empty slug field so it can't construct the URL.

Comment: I've seen that same sort of path syntax be used within the Unix terminal tracebacks, working with GUI's or anything that involves file paths of some sort.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. That's just the entry from your urls.py that you were trying to match.

Comment: With respect are you saying that line is easily readable for a beginner? Because I've been at this for 2 years now and have absolutely no clue what information I'm supposed to take from that line. This: ?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+ is by no means common knowledge for anyone and I want to know what it means and how to read it

Comment: I guess you should google regular expressions then. Anyway, `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+` equals to repeating alphanumeric characters plus "_" and your `project.category.slug` is empty (""), which isn't an alphanumeric character.

Comment: No I'm not saying that at all. That is a regex, which is the previous way URLs were defined in Django before the `path()` syntax was introduced. For some reason, when the new syntax was brought in the NoReverseMatch errors were not updated to use it (I'll file a bug). But again this has nothing to do with file paths, and you are unlikely to see this error anywhere other than in this exact circumstance, ie Django reverse match failures.

Comment: Okay, thank you! That was the answer I was looking for is what to consider this. I can google search it now because I'm 100% certain I can find some example of regex online. Thanks again.